# making adaptive layout for all iPhone devices

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, interface-builder

I'm learning Swift now and I'm trying to make UIs for my personal project. I watched some of the autolayout, stack views, and adoptive layout tutorials, but I cannot display UIs if the device gets smaller or bigger. The first image below is when I add the top constraint to the label, "welcome", to 20 points.

[image]

I can display all of my UIs, labels, the progress bar, image view, and the button, "check my if then". I added vertical spacing of 16pt for UIs so, you can see a small gap between those UIs. However, the problem is, it looks ok for the iPhone SE screen, but for the iPhone 11 you see the huge space at the bottom.

And here is the second image, make the UI image view (a bigger pink square in the middle) vertically centers and lower the UI a little.

[image]

Same as the first image, I added 16pt spacing between vertical items, and you will see the small gap between them. But for the iPhone 11, since I put the pink image view vertically centered, both the top and bottom have a bigger gap and the UI looks poorly.

The layout I want to make is something like this.
[image]

Even if the screen size changes (and I only care about iPhone screens for now), I can still see the same UIs with smaller version or bigger version. Now I add vertical spacing of 16pt to each UI, so that makes UIs tighten, but not sure how I can change the spacing depends on the screen horizontal sizes. I hope this makes sense. I want to know what I'm missing and should study or any suggestions when I work on making UIs.
I'm not sure this helps or not, but here are my constraints...
[image]

I'm using interface builder for this project.

Answer (score -1):

UI design involves a lot more than just getting spacing / sizing to adjust between device / screen sizes.

How do you want it to look when the device is rotated? Or on an iPad screen?

There are "UI Designers" who make a lot of money because they are very, very good at it.

You say *"I'm learning Swift now"* ... well, the best approach is to simply read more and more tutorials / articles / blogs / documentation / etc, and keep experimenting and learning.

While you're working on it, think about how the elements are "divided up" on your layout...

- It appears you want the top elements - the menu and logout buttons and the Welcome label - to be consistently sized and spaced.
- You probably want the progress labels to stay vertically close to the progress bar.
- It looks like you want the pink (I'm guessing, image) view to be square - 1:1 ratio.
- Then the "button" at the bottom.
- And you want some even spacing.

So, you have essentially **4** elements to think about instead of **8**.

Here's source for a Storyboard that may help you along:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="16096" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="172-Ys-2E0">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="16087"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="Stack View standard spacing" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="gg1-88-ZEb">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="172-Ys-2E0" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="W95-f5-z1M">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="G3C-2N-hBY">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="12" width="46" height="36"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="36" id="vVB-Sc-Yi1"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <color key="tintColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                <state key="normal" image="menuButton">
                                    <preferredSymbolConfiguration key="preferredSymbolConfiguration" configurationType="pointSize" pointSize="28" weight="black"/>
                                </state>
                            </button>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="NAA-cu-1GI">
                                <rect key="frame" x="263" y="7" width="92" height="46"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" weight="black" pointSize="28"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="logout">
                                    <color key="titleColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                </state>
                            </button>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="fWQ-7J-f7E">
                                <rect key="frame" x="32" y="123" width="311" height="528"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" distribution="equalSpacing" spacingType="standard" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="nXY-UB-zXF">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="13" width="311" height="502"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <view hidden="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="OP6-NH-JHF">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="-6" width="311" height="2"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="2" id="3UY-3c-rC3"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </view>
                                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="kXp-zq-J6l">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="311" height="44"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Wax-WV-I2N">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="311" height="24"/>
                                                        <subviews>
                                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Today's progress:" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Aum-nh-bCH">
                                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="262" height="24"/>
                                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="20"/>
                                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                            </label>
                                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="750" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="4 / 6" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="irl-97-Tfc">
                                                                <rect key="frame" x="270" y="0.0" width="41" height="24"/>
                                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="20"/>
                                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </subviews>
                                                    </stackView>
                                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="tzW-47-BdA">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="32" width="311" height="12"/>
                                                        <subviews>
                                                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="c06-2d-LeR">
                                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="311" height="12"/>
                                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.84866023059999995" green="0.84878283740000005" blue="0.84863340850000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                            </imageView>
                                                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ycO-Yh-oSC">
                                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="233.5" height="12"/>
                                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.9215936065" green="0.38732314109999999" blue="0.51481616500000005" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                            </imageView>
                                                        </subviews>
                                                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                                                        <constraints>
                                                            <constraint firstItem="ycO-Yh-oSC" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="c06-2d-LeR" secondAttribute="centerY" id="7wt-6I-EVf"/>
                                                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="c06-2d-LeR" secondAttribute="bottom" id="9s3-pc-VkJ"/>
                                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="c06-2d-LeR" secondAttribute="trailing" id="EcS-Rm-Ynx"/>
                                                            <constraint firstItem="ycO-Yh-oSC" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="c06-2d-LeR" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="0.75" id="HSf-Y9-Shk"/>
                                                            <constraint firstItem="ycO-Yh-oSC" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="c06-2d-LeR" secondAttribute="leading" id="TNa-dw-RcH"/>
                                                            <constraint firstItem="c06-2d-LeR" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="tzW-47-BdA" secondAttribute="leading" id="dHn-DI-OKX"/>
                                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="12" id="hXb-9X-U4k"/>
                                                            <constraint firstItem="c06-2d-LeR" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="tzW-47-BdA" secondAttribute="top" id="qYp-Y2-WeM"/>
                                                            <constraint firstItem="ycO-Yh-oSC" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="c06-2d-LeR" secondAttribute="height" id="vco-oo-SHu"/>
                                                        </constraints>
                                                    </view>
                                                </subviews>
                                            </stackView>
                                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Ga2-sg-ARc">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="71.5" width="311" height="311"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.94554942850000001" green="0.78171783689999996" blue="0.78158324960000003" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="Ga2-sg-ARc" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="tT1-Hj-Sc1"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </imageView>
                                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" alignment="center" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="K4b-he-ckY">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="410" width="311" height="62.5"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="kat-Ko-rc5">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="62" y="0.0" width="187" height="62.5"/>
                                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.7673358321" green="0.767447412" blue="0.76731151340000003" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                        <constraints>
                                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="kat-Ko-rc5" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="180:60" id="TrG-te-fP9"/>
                                                        </constraints>
                                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="30"/>
                                                        <state key="normal" title="button">
                                                            <color key="titleColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                        </state>
                                                    </button>
                                                </subviews>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstItem="kat-Ko-rc5" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="K4b-he-ckY" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="0.6" id="J8V-xL-g2t"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </stackView>
                                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="icI-mg-H6h">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="500" width="311" height="2"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="2" id="PNC-Wv-Qma"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </view>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="nXY-UB-zXF" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="fWQ-7J-f7E" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="0.95" id="3Gx-N3-PZn"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="nXY-UB-zXF" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="fWQ-7J-f7E" secondAttribute="centerY" id="9VX-uV-FqY"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="nXY-UB-zXF" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="fWQ-7J-f7E" secondAttribute="leading" id="BlQ-S7-cAD"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="nXY-UB-zXF" secondAttribute="trailing" id="yDc-bo-7JZ"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Welcome!!" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="OKM-oK-ll3">
                                <rect key="frame" x="32" y="64" width="179" height="43"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="36"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99993449450000005" green="0.91130131479999998" blue="0.77088779210000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="OKM-oK-ll3" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="ORM-kG-UNT" secondAttribute="leading" constant="32" id="JQu-N0-9NK"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ORM-kG-UNT" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="fWQ-7J-f7E" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="32" id="PRk-Hu-crq"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="G3C-2N-hBY" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="ORM-kG-UNT" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="R7V-zj-Ieg"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="fWQ-7J-f7E" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="OKM-oK-ll3" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="16" id="UTC-W0-Ja0"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ORM-kG-UNT" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="NAA-cu-1GI" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="VAk-b0-olQ"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="G3C-2N-hBY" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="ORM-kG-UNT" secondAttribute="top" constant="12" id="ZgO-nA-Y6f"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="fWQ-7J-f7E" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="ORM-kG-UNT" secondAttribute="leading" constant="32" id="a8r-Yh-0YR"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="NAA-cu-1GI" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="G3C-2N-hBY" secondAttribute="centerY" id="e4E-py-4P7"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="OKM-oK-ll3" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="G3C-2N-hBY" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="16" id="i4b-Wy-DZC"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ORM-kG-UNT" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="fWQ-7J-f7E" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="16" id="jZt-27-Nuv"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="ORM-kG-UNT"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="smv-6h-Rg0" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="34.782608695652179" y="276.5625"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="menuButton" width="46" height="40"/>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Using that, I get this on SE (1), 8, XS Max and 11:

[image]